# Display moderator messages in the global inbox, not as a site-only dropdown

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, global-inbox, moderator-messages

When another moderator sends a direct user message, the notification appears for all other moderators as a dropdown alert. This is somewhat distracting, and also impossible to get back to once it's closed. I feel like this type of alert makes more sense *for moderators* as a global inbox notification, since it's more of a "you should read this message" inbox type item. For users on the receiving end, it should probably be *both* a global inbox notification *and* a dropdown message, to ensure that they receive it.

Comment: You know you _can_ get back to it once that's closed, just from the mod menu

Comment: I know, but the user can't get back to it, hence the suggestion that it show up in _both_ for them.

Comment: I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Moderator message notifications should be red in the global inbox for those involved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133837/moderator-message-notifications-should-be-red-in-the-global-inbox), this has now been implemented as a "notification" (not an inbox message), and will be changed to a proper inbox message soon.

Answer (score 5):

The users **also typically get an email -- you know, a real, physical email in their email inbox** -- and that contains the text with a link to the moderator message URL, so I'm not sure I can agree with this.

It is the default option when sending a moderator message.

Comment: I believe @Nhinkle asks for a Global Inbox option for **moderators** so that it's not lost.. (perhaps lost is the wrong word since you can go and fetch it again) rather than the end user.

Comment: @sathya I beg to differ, see above comment "I know, but **the user can't get back to it**, hence the suggestion that it show up in both for them"

Comment: I'm asking for both: **I feel like this type of alert makes more sense for _moderators_ as a global inbox notification**.

Comment: @JeffAtwood any possibility of reconsidering this request? It's a message, so really it should show up in one's inbox - inboxes are for messages, right? I understand they can an email as well, but that doesn't mean the format for delivery on-site can't be adjusted as well. Is there any reason _not_ to have it be both?

Answer (score 0):

*When I logged in today I could swear I saw a moderator message appear* right before Firefox died loading another page*.

I don't know what it was.  I can't find anything in my inbox which would generate such a message.  Perhaps it was a badge notification or a notice on an open bounty? or?

But I don't see any recent badges that I didn't already know about.  My bounties still have a few days to go...??  (and haven't generated much interest anyways...)

It would be awesome if there was some simple way just to keep a record of which notifications I recently *should've seen* barring the gamma ray burst which just hosed my browser...

Note:  This doesn't have to be a queue, it could simply be listed in the profile under **activity** as a separate sub-tag **system notifications** (or perhaps simply **system**).